# How to print out one random String from an array

Tags: java, arrays, printing, system

Hi I was wondering how I can print out one random value of an array instead of two of them. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{

    String[] currentRoom;
    String[][] rooms = new String [2] [2];
    rooms [0] [0] = "Start";
    rooms [0] [1] = "Treasure Room 1";
    rooms [1] [0] = "Goblin Hive 1";
    rooms [1] [1] = "Spider Nest";

    Random rand = new Random();
    {

        currentRoom = rooms[rand.nextInt(rooms.length)];

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(currentRoom));

    }
}
```

When I print it out it will say two values from my array, something like:         ["Start", "Treasure Room1"]   and I need it to print out just one value like: ["Start"] or just ["Spider Nest1"]. I was wondering how I can solve this.

Any help is appreciated:)

Answer (score 6):

You need to generate a random index in the second dimension, like this:

```
String[] currentRoomRow = rooms[rand.nextInt(rooms.length)];
String currentRoom = currentRoomRow[rand.nextInt(currentRoom.length)];
System.out.println(currentRoom);
```

This is OK when all rows have the same size; if they do not, the above code would "favor" items from "shorter" rows. Fixing this deficiency would require more preparation: you would need to "flatten" your array, generate a single random up to the number of items, and then pick an item from the flattened array.

Answer (score 2):

This is a two-dimensional array. By using only one index, you'll get an array (maybe with multiple values). By `using rooms [0]` you'll return `["Start", "Treasure Room1"]`.

Thus you have to pass 2 indexes.

Dasblinkenlight's solution seems to be the best.